# Debugger does not automatically attach in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

Anyone have a problem with the debugger not automatically attaching when trying to debug an asp .net application? I can debug fine if I attach it to the local visual studio web server process.

I have all the debug settings in the project configuration set correctly, and I can debug other projects just fine, so there's some project-specific thing that's not right.

Comment: I've had the worst problems getting the VS2002 debugger to attach. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Are you using IE? what version?

Comment: No, Firefox is my default browser.